# CreateProcess from a Handle and not from Path

Tags: c++, handle, createprocess

is there any way to create a process from a `File Handle` that was returned by `CreateFile()`?

The `CreateProcess()` function can only create a process from a path to the file, and I can't find any way to create a process from a `File Handle`

EDIT: I need to create a process directly from a `File Handle`. I can't create the process from the path.

Comment: You can get a file name from a file handle.  Is there a reason you need to create a process from an handle?

Comment: Yes. I need to create a process directly from a File Handle. I can't create the process from the path

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot create a process directly from a file handle. But you could get the file path from the handle using [GetFinalPathNameByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then use CreateProcess on the path.

**NOTE** That the GetFilePathNameByHandle API is only available on Vista & up so if you want to support older operating systems you'll have to get creative.. :)  See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366789%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to create a process directly from a File Handle

Comment: @user1438233 as you can see the CreateProcess API doesn't take a handle. It takes a path. There is a way to get the path from the handle but there is no way to just call CreateProcess on a handle. The answer to your question as forumlated is "no".

Comment: @user1438233 out of pure curiosity - what is it that you are trying to do that prevents you from using this indirect method?

Comment: I am opening a file in a special way that is supported by CreateFile(), but not by CreateProcess(), therefore i must use CreateFile to open the File.

Answer (score 2):

http://pastebin.com/WvWABiRu May help you. If you go over the native API (NtCreateProcess) you only need a file handle (you can specify a random path forRtlCreateProcessParameters afaik). But you have to do a lot of work to get the process to actually execute.